# My hard drive is hanging for a couple seconds at a time

Tags: hard-drive, windows-8.1, ssd, freeze

I just got a new laptop (an MSI ghost). It has a 128 GB SSD and a 1 TB HDD. Everything's fine with the solid state drive, but the hard drive hangs for a couple seconds at a time. The most obvious effect of this is when I save files to the hard drive, the program in question pauses freezes for a couple seconds before saving. The rest of Windows doesn't freeze, just the program saving the file.

Things I've noticed:

- The hard drive seems to be "falling asleep" after a certain period of time. If I save something a bunch of times in a row, it's fine, but I stop saving things for a couple of minutes the problem comes back.
- The problem also affects reading from the hard drive. I've had music pause for a couple of seconds while playing, and I'm pretty sure it's the same problem.
- Enabling the option "Turn off Windows write-cache buffer flushing on the device" fixes the problem, but that's also a terrible thing to enable, apparently.
- I did a fresh install of Windows to see if it would fix the problem, but it didn't, unfortunately.

I don't think the hard drive is broken, as this laptop is really new, and nothing else suspicious is happening. Anyone know what might be wrong?

Comment: Information about the mechanical HDD would he helpful.

Comment: Try Control Panel > Power Options > "Advanced settings" of the current power plan, Expand "hard disk", and disable turning the hard drive off.

Comment: Check your event viewer and see if there are any errors. I've had a similar (but much worse) issue with my main SSD where it would lock up for about a minute, no reads nor writes would be possible, the disk activity LED would stay lit up and the OS would freeze entirely. A minute later, everything would unfreeze and an error "The device...did not respond within the timeout period".

Comment: I looked through the event viewer and the closest thing I found was "The server {1B1F472E-3221-4826-97DB-2C2324D389AE} did not register with DCOM within the required timeout." I don't think that's related because I was triggering the lag a bunch of times to test things out and I don't have that many errors and the timestamps don't match up.

Comment: Oh, Ramhound, I missed your comment! The HDD is just some random one, I don't know if you could even find any specific information about this one. Anyway, here it is: http://www.techspot.com/products/storage/hgst-hitachi-travelstar-7k1000-sata600-hts7210-a9e-series.94802/

Answer (score -1):

Couple of things you can try:
 - Open Task  Manager or Activity Monitor and see if CPU is getting jammed or memory RAM is low?
 - Check for Fan. Do you hear it running ?
 - Turn off Antivirus if that is causing too much of disk IO